# Watching a folder with Chokidar outside of application with docker

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, watch, chokidar

I have a application that watches for changes made in a folder, but I want to be able to change which folder is being watched in the users local system. If possible, a file path would be able to be pasted in the docker-compose file, and the application would watch the folder that the user chose.

As of now, the user would have to go into the path of the volume in their local machine to make changes to the "watch-folder" instead of choosing their own watch folder

Currently the code is -

```
const watcher = chokidar.watch('watch-folder', {
    persistent:true,
})
```

I'd like to possibly add something along these lines for the user to be able to add which folder they specified

```
watcher.add('FOLDER-FROM-DOCKER-COMPOSE');
```

Comment: You can't watch for file system changes outside of the container. The container's file system is isolated from the host's file system. You should probably hardcode a specific path to watch inside the container, then you can mount a path from the host machine to the path which is watched inside the container using a volume. You can declare the volume in the docker-compose.yaml.

Comment: I did this but the application won't detect changes to the folder being updated after the containers have already been started. The user would have to restart the containers for new changes to be shown in the application @JakeHolzinger

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with bindmounts in docker. I had the application point to a specific path in the container, and the bindmount mounts a path from the host machine to that container.

Here is what my docker-compose file looks like, you can replace {PATH} with a path in your local machine and replace {CONTAINERPATH} with the path in your container.

```
version: "3"
services:
  api-server:
    build: ./ExpressBackend
    volumes:
      - "{PATH}:{CONTAINERPATH}"
    image: express
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - react-express
```

Tip - Container Path is set in the Dockerfile with the WORKDIR keyword